# which IP address connects to my server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip, command-history

For some internal reasons, several people in our company are sharing the same USERNAME when connecting to SERVER, but they connect from different clients and machines.

We need to **track what each IP address does on the server**.

Can you suggest how to store the time history of the commands organized by IP address, and not by USERNAME (which would be much easier)? Is that even possible?

Specifics:
SERVER has Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS installed, and people are connecting and doing operations on it from both Windows and Linux machines.

Comment: Whoever voted down, could at least explain how to improve this question?

Comment: On Linux, both the `last` command and a perusal of `/var/log/auth.log`  will give you those info, no sweat.

Comment: And I agree your question does not deserve a downvote, I redressed your situation.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Thank you for your comments. It's the right starting point to fix my problem. This file is huge and contains so many lines like: 'Received disconnect from 121.*:  [preauth]'. Anyway I suppose I can use this content to track who was connected when a certain problem happened.Thank you

Comment: The line you mention, `'Received disconnect from 121.*: [preauth]`, is what happens when one tries to log in, and cannot/does not try to authenticate. It might be a break-in attempt.  Keep your eyes wide open.

Comment: You may want to ban some IPs, if you see many attempts to breakin from the same address. Use `iptables` for that.

Comment: I'll certainly ban some of them. Thank you for your comments, it was really helpful.